# CSS changing (transitioning) background color

Tags: css, animation, colors, background

I am a code beginner. Sometime ago I saw a github project to make the background colour change automatically and gradually from red to white to green to black.

It seems impossible to find it again and I am struggling whilst look for options on the internet. I guess I am really using the right words to explain myself.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@keyframes bgcolour {
    0% {background-color: red;}
    50% {background-color: green;}
    100% {background-color: blue;}
}

body {
    animation: bgcolour 10s infinite alternate; /* Don't forget the "alternate" which reverses the animation to avoid a jump form 100% to 0% */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nstht/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/cMvRP/4/)**

```
body 
{
    background:red;
    animation:myfirst 5s;
    -moz-animation:myfirst 5s infinite; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}


@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
{
    0%   {background:red;}
    25%  {background:white;}
    50%  {background:green;}
    75%  {background:black;}
    100%   {background:red;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    0%   {background:red;}
    25%  {background:white;}
    50%  {background:green;}
    75%  {background:black;}
    100%   {background:red;}
}
```